# Can the following inequality be directly infered?

Tags: inequality

If we have a condition as follows

$$\log(1+\mathbf{h}_2^* \mathbf{\Sigma}  \mathbf{h}_2) \leq \log(1+\mathbf{h}_1^* \mathbf{\Sigma}  \mathbf{h}_1)$$

where $\Sigma$ is positive semi definite matrix given below and the notation * means conjugate transpose. While $\mathbf{h}_i$ are 2 by 1 vectors.  Can we directly infer that

$$|\mathbf{h}_2|^2\stackrel{?}{\leq} |\mathbf{h}_1|^2 $$

if yes, what would be the reason for such a simplification.

Looking forward for your ideas.

The matrix $\Sigma$ is given below

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1-|\rho_1|^2 & \rho_3 - \rho_1 \rho_2^* \\
\rho_3^* - \rho_1^*\rho_2 & 1-|\rho_2|^2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$|\rho_i |\leq 1 \forall i =[1:3]$$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what user2566092 suggested, consider the vectors $h_1 = (0, 1)$ and $h_2 = (2, 0)$.  Then $h_2$ is twice as long as $h_1$.  Consider the  $\Sigma$ with $\rho_1 = 1$ and $\rho_2 = \rho_3 = 0$.

In that case, $\Sigma h_1 = (0, 1)$ so

$$h_1^*\Sigma h_1 = 1$$

Likewise, $\Sigma h_2 = (0, 0)$ so $$h_2^*\Sigma h_2 = 0$$

So we have $h_2^*\Sigma h_2 \leq h_1^*\Sigma h_1$ but $h_2$ is longer than $h_1$.  This is a counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

The log and adding 1 is unnecessary. You want to know if $b_2^T \Sigma b_2 \leq b_1^T \Sigma b_1$ implies the euclidean length of $b_2$ is less than or equal to the length of $b_1$. To answer this, just take a diagonal $\Sigma$, say in dimension 2, where the first diagonal element is larger than the second. Then take $b_1$ and $b_2$ to be multiples of standard basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, where the length of $b_1$ is sufficiently close but smaller than the length of $b_2$. This shows the conclusion in general is not necessarily true.

Comment: Actually my $\Sigma$ matrix has special format, I will update my question. Logically I believe the inequality is correct, I cant have a solid mathematial proof.